# JTable not able to add scroll bars

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

I am having JTable which has records which can't fit into it so I have decided to add scrollbars. However, the scroll bar isn't appearing. What am I doing wrong?

```
new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

            table.setBounds(10, 73, 850, 850);
```

According to answers I have it like this now:

```
JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane(table, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
            table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

            panel.setBounds(10, 73, 850, 850);
            contentPane.add(table);
```

Now the table isn't even shown.

Comment: you need to provide `setbounds` to `JScrollPane` not to `JTable`. And avoid using `null` layouts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> contentPane.add(table);

You are removing the table from the scrollpane.

You must add the scroll pane to the frame. The code should be:

```
contentPane.add(panel);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
table.setBounds(10, 73, 850, 850);
```

you're shooting yourself in the foot by constraining the size of the JTable, preventing it from expaining (and thus showing the JScrollPane's scrollbars) when needed.

Never, never, never set absolute sizes of any components, avoid null layouts but rather let the component's preferred sizes and the layout managers do that for you. Yours is a common newbie mistake since it *seems* that it should be easier to create complex GUI's by setting all the sizes and positions of things yourself, but you'll soon find that this is a fallacy, that when you do this, you unnecessarily limit the flexibility and updatability of your GUI, and also you'll find that it will look terrible on all platforms and screen resolutions other than your own. Again, learn and use the layout managers.

Comment: Thanks, how can I then set min size?

Comment: @OndrejTokar the `JScrollPane` should be the one you size, within any LayoutManager.